# NASA World Wind integration with Netbeans Platform

Tags: netbeans-platform, worldwind

I am trying to integrate NASA World Wind Java library in a NetBeans platform project. I am using Windows XP with Netbeans 7.2 and WorldWind 1.4.0.

I can open and run world wind examples as netbeans project. However when I try to use world wind components on Netbeans platform, I receive exceptions stating that **`javax.media.openGL.GLException: Method "glActiveTexture" not available` and `javax.media.openGL.GLException: DXTn compressed textures not supported by this graphics card`.**

After receiving exceptions I can see the background space, stars and the atmosphere contour but not the globe. Since I can run the world wind examples without an error, I do not think the problem is actually related to the graphics card. I think there might be some compatibility issues between netbeans platform and the world wind libraries.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7630776/843318